# Handling newly devices added to or removed from a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists that I need to intersect. This is what I'm doing.

```
    var dfuDevices = _dfuMonitor.GetDevices();

    // new devices
    dfuDevices.Except(Devices).AsParallel().ForAll(device => {
        if (device.GetType() == typeof(DFUDeviceModel)) {
            OnDfuDeviceDetected(device);
        }
    });

    // removed devices
    Devices.Except(dfuDevices).AsParallel().ForAll(device => {
        if (device.Equals(ConnectedDevice))
            Disconnect();

        if (device is DFUDeviceModel)
            OnDfuDeviceRemoved(device);
    });

    // refresh list
    Devices = Devices.Intersect(dfuDevices);
```

I need to react accordingly to each item that is either removed or added. Is there any way to reduce this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Detecting changes**

What you need is an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

---

Your code is very short so there is not much to comment on but there is one more thing that you can *improve*.

> ```
> dfuDevices.Except(Devices).AsParallel().ForAll(device => {
>     if (device.GetType() == typeof(DFUDeviceModel)) {
>         OnDfuDeviceDetected(device);
>     }
> });
> ```

You can simplify this by using the [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extension that

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
dfuDevices
    .Except(Devices)
    .OfType<DFUDeviceModel>()
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(OnDfuDeviceDetected);
```

Comment: Thats something I need to dig into myself. +1

Comment: There's a small difference between `OfType` and the existing code. The existing code checks for the exact type whereas the `OfType` version allows subclasses.